how to iterate and populate table view or data grid view
I have a vb.net project where i get resultset from ms access. I want to iterate through the records and populate data grid or data table. However i need to add a button in the last column where if a record in the resultset matches a predicate I will add a button like "Add" or "Delete".
conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\moviesdb.accdb")

conn.Open()

adp = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from movie_master where audience_age <= @audienceAge", conn)
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@audienceAge", userAge)

Using ds As New DataSet
    adp.Fill(ds, 0)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(watchlistbutton)
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(removeWatchlistbutton)
End Using


The above code populates the datagrid, however it does not provide a mechanism to add watchlist button or removewatchlist button based on a predicate like if the user has already added the movie to the watchlist, then show removeWatchlistbutton else show watchlistbutton.
Thanks in advance.

Please remove the tags vba and vb6 from your question, they are not relevant.

IIRC correctly, Access only supports positional parameter arguments, so you'd need a ? instead of @audienceAge in the SQL string. Also, that Parameters.Add() call is NOT doing what you expect. It should be AddWithValue(), or an Add() overload that sets a database column type. Finally, I'd set up those buttons in the VS forms designer, separate from the code.

@JoelCoehoorn Yes, only the parameter's position is considered, the name assigned to the parameter is irrelevant, because it's ignored. You can specify anything you want. If it's human-readable, it may be useful to someone, as a visual aid. Otherwise, specifying ? may be useful to indicate that it's a positional parameter, the order matters, not the name. Whatever floats your boat

@Jimi My understanding is the Parameters.Add() call can us any human-readable name you want, but the SQL statement had to use ? for the placeholder.

@JoelCoehoorn It's the same thing for both. It's simple to test

It is worth mentioning that ignoring the parameter name is specific to OLEDB. Other providers are not positional.

You are welcome. Also, since you are new to StackOverflow, I would like to inform you that you can upvote good answers (if you have enough points) and accept the answer that helped you the most by checking the tick mark next to the Answer. On this site an upvote or an accepted answer counts as a "thanks".

I did not find a way to change the visibility of the button; however, there is a way to display or hide the button caption by changing UseColumnTextForButtonValue of the cell.
This is how the button is added:
dataGridView1.DataSource = ...
Dim deleteButton = New DataGridViewButtonColumn With {
    .Name = "colDeleteButton",
    .Text = "Delete",
    .HeaderText = ""
}
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(deleteButton)

As an example I display the "Delete" caption when a certain cell value is even (value  Mod 2 = 0)
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colDeleteButton" Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim buttonCell = CType(row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewButtonCell)
        'Adapt the condition and the cell index to an appropriate value
        buttonCell.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = CInt(row.Cells(2).Value) Mod 2 = 0
    End If
End Sub

We also must test this condition when the button is pressed to perform its action only when needed
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellContentClick

    If dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "colDeleteButton" AndAlso
        'Adapt the condition and the cell index to an appropriate value
        CInt(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value) Mod 2 = 0 Then

        MessageBox.Show("deleting...")
    End If
End Sub

